# Why my application works well but when I try to modularize it, it doesn't work properly?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shinymodules

My application has two selectInputs. It updates the secound selectInput depending on the first selectInput and then it plots a timeline for df data. The app works completely well, but when I try to modularize it, it doesn't work properly (just the selectInputs work, but no plot is built). I have created a minimal example. I really appreciate any help everybody can provide.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

# data preparation
df<-data.frame(Name1<-c("Aix galericulata","Grus grus","    Alces alces"),
               Name2<-c("Mandarin Duck","Common Crane"  ,"Elk"),
               eventDate<-c("2015-03-11","2015-03-10","2015-03-10"),
               individualCount<-c(1, 10, 1)
)
colnames(df)<-c("Name1","Name2","eventDate","individualCount")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# module dataselect
dataselect_ui<- function(id) {
  ns<-NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("Nametype"),"Select a name type",
                choices=c("Name1","Name2","choose"),selected = "choose"),
    
    selectInput(ns("Name"),"Select a name",
                choices="",selected = "",selectize=TRUE)
  )
}
dataselect_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    

    # Putting columns Name1 and Nam2 of df in one column called nameType using melt()function
    # This format of data is needed for the choices argument of updateSelectizeInput()
    df2<-reshape2::melt(df,id=c("eventDate","individualCount"))
    colnames(df2)<-c("eventDate","individualCount","nameType","Name")
    
    observeEvent(
      input$Nametype,
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "Name", "Select a name", 
                           choices = unique(df2$Name[df2$nameType==input$Nametype]),selected = ""))
    
    
    # finalDf() is the data used to plot the timeline
    finalDf<-reactive({
      if(input$Name=="choose"){
        return(NULL)
        
      }
      if(input$Name==""){
        return(NULL)
        
      }
      if(input$Nametype=="choose"){
        return(NULL)
        
      } 
      
      # if the first selectInput is set to Name1, from df select rows their Name1 column is 
      # equal to the second selectInput value
      else if(input$Nametype=="Name1"){
        finalDf<-df[which(df$Name1==input$Name) ,]
        
      } 
      # if the first selectInput is set to Name2, from df select rows their Name2 column is 
      # equal to the second selectInput value
      else if(input$Nametype=="Name2"){
        finalDf<-df[which(df$Name2==input$Name) ,]
        
      }
      return(
        reactive({
          input$Name
        })
      )
      
    })
  })
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  navbarPage(
    "app",
    tabPanel("plot", 
             sidebarPanel(
               
               dataselect_ui("dataselect")
               
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               plotlyOutput("timeline")
               
             )
             
    )
  )
)


server <- function(session,input, output) {
  
  dataselect_server("dataselect")
  # timeline plot
  output$timeline <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$Name)
    p<-ggplot(finalDf(),aes(x=eventDate,y=individualCount)) +geom_point(alpha=0.2, shape=21, color="black",fill="red",size=5)+
      labs( x = "Date Event",y= "Individual Count") +theme_bw()
    p<-ggplotly(p)
    p
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Because your `renderPlotly` is in the module but not your `plotlyOutput`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I took the renderPlotly out of the module and put it in the main app, but still like before, the app doesn't draw the plot.

Comment: Because you have `req(input$Name)` but the `Name` input is inside the module.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent  For that, I added a       return(
        reactive({
          input$Name
        })    to the end of dataselect_server. But the problem still exists. Isn't it sufficient?
      )

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Should I do anything else for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return `input$Name` from the server module, as you correctly do, you have to use the returned value of this module in `renderPlotly`:

```r
server <- function(session,input, output) {
  
  input_Name <- dataselect_server("dataselect")

  # timeline plot
  output$timeline <- renderPlotly({
    req(input_Name()) # don't forget the parentheses!
    p<-ggplot(finalDf(),aes(x=eventDate,y=individualCount)) +geom_point(alpha=0.2, shape=21, color="black",fill="red",size=5)+
      labs( x = "Date Event",y= "Individual Count") +theme_bw()
    p<-ggplotly(p)
    p
  })

}
```

---

## EDIT

There is a problem in your code: your `return` statement of `reactive(input$Name)` is inside the reactive conductor `finalDf`.

Moreover you need to return `finalDf` as well, to use it outside the module.

So:

```r
    dataselect_server <- function(id) {
      moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

        ......
        
        finalDf <- reactive({

          if(input$Name=="choose"){
            return(NULL)            
          }
          if(input$Name==""){
            return(NULL)            
          }
          if(input$Nametype=="choose"){
            return(NULL)            
          } 
 
          if(input$Nametype=="Name1") {
            finalDf <- df[which(df$Name1==input$Name) ,]   
          } else if(input$Nametype=="Name2") {
            finalDf <- df[which(df$Name2==input$Name) ,]
          }

          return(finalDf)
          
        })

      return(
        list("finalDf" = finalDf, "input_Name" = reactive(input$Name))
      )

      })
    }
```

and:

```r
server <- function(session,input, output) {
  
  module_outputs <- dataselect_server("dataselect")
  input_Name <- module_outputs$input_Name
  finalDf    <- module_outputs$finalDf

  # timeline plot
  output$timeline <- renderPlotly({
    req(input_Name()) # don't forget the parentheses!
    p <- ggplot(finalDf(), aes(x = eventDate, y = individualCount)) 
 + geom_point(alpha = 0.2, shape = 21,  color = "black", fill = "red", size = 5) +
      labs(x = "Date Event", y = "Individual Count") + theme_bw()
    ggplotly(p)
  })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did it, but unfortunately I got another error: could not find function "finalDf"

Comment: .In my real application, I want to add another module that is related to a plot. The input of this plot is finalDf(). To write this module, I put the plotOutput() in module_ui and the renderPlot() in module_server. And I also add the req(input_Name()) before ggplot() in renderPlot(). But it gives an Error: could not find function "input_Name". Should I do anything else? @Stéphane Laurent